# assigning a value to many members of a class

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
class A
  attr_accessor :dab
  ....
end
```

Now I have an array of instances of A, say

```
arr = [A.new, A.new, A.new]
```

And now I want to set a value to all instances of class `A` present in the array `arr`. Is there a shortcut in ruby/rails to do this?

In addition, I do have `A` inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`

And my actual need is:

```
A.find_all_by_some_condition.all.dabs = 2
```

So, all found objects will have `dab` set to 2.

Is there shortcut for this?

Comment: my 1st attempt is to add a method `dab= value` to array class, keep this code added to the file of A class at the end. And being smart/stupid check that dab= is processing only instances of A class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the items of class A from an array you can use select/find_all

`arr.select { |el| el.class == A }` or `arr.select { |el| A === el }`

To achieve your actual result though you are looking to assign a value to several objects, not their corresponding class. class A does not define the actual objects it just defines the blueprint that the objects use when getting created. So finding a way to assign a value of all instances of A is not what you are after (although I might have missed the point of what you were asking for)

To assign a value to an array of object this works:

```
A.find_all_by_some_condition.each { |a| a.dab = 2 }
```

Perhaps you want to save them after that, now `arr.each(&:save)` might come in handy. Go look up the ampersand if you don't know it already. Very useful.

Comment: You can use `#each` with an ampersand/symbol/proc, just like you can with `#map`. Map is really for transforming data structures, not for iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly by default, however you could build something like that using Ruby's `method_missing`.

Two solutions:

**Solution 1 - Use a wrapper class**

We'll call this class `MArray` for multi-assign-array.

```
class MArray
  def initialize(inner_array)
    @inner = inner_array
  end

  def method_missing(meth, value)
    # Check if assignement, and if it is then run mass-assign
    if meth.to_s =~ /^\w+=$/
      @inner.each { |itm| itm.send(meth, value) }
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "MArray: not an assignment"
    end
  end
end
```

We also need to add support for `MArray` in `Array`, so that the wrapping will take place. We'll call the method `mas` for "mass-assignment":

```
class Array
  def mas
    # Wrap MArray around self
    MArray.new(self)
  end
end
```

Usage is simple:

```
Blob = Struct.new(:dab)
arr = [Blob.new] * 3
arr.mas.dab = 123
arr
=> [#<struct Blob dab=123>, #<struct Blob dab=123>, #<struct Blob dab=123>]
```

**Solution 2 - Create mass-assignment support directly into `Array`**

This is a bit more "dangerous" since we directly modify `method_missing` in `Array`. It *could* create some strange side-effects (for example if `method_missing` has already been redefined by some other library, or you accidentally call a mass-assign while you didn't mean to).

It works by trying to detect assignments with plural words (words ending with `s`), and then triggering the mass-assignment:

```
class Array
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    # Check for plural assignment, and as an added safety check also
    # see if all elements in the array support the assignment:
    if meth.to_s =~ /^(\w+)s=$/ && 
       self.all? { |itm| itm.respond_to?("#{$1}=") }
      self.each { |itm| itm.send("#{$1}=", *args) }
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Usage then becomes even shorter than with `MArray`:

```
Blob = Struct.new(:dab)
arr = [Blob.new] * 3
arr.dabs = 123
arr
=> [#<struct Blob dab=123>, #<struct Blob dab=123>, #<struct Blob dab=123>]
```